# Read html files and find js/css and minify that and replace js/css name with old name - Gulp

Tags: gulp, copy, extract, rename, minify

I have a html file like this:

```
<html class="h-100">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <title>Login</title>

   <!-- main css -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/vendors/clarity-ui/css/clarity-ui.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/scss/main.css">
</head>
```

I want to read html file for do that:

1. Extract name and path css or js file
2. Minify css or js
3. Copy to `dist` directory
4. Rename css or js path/name to new location and name

How to do that with Gulp and Gulp plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [gulp-useref](https://github.com/jonkemp/gulp-useref).  It has a good example:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
useref = require('gulp-useref'),
gulpif = require('gulp-if'),
uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
minifyCss = require('gulp-clean-css');

gulp.task('html', function () {
         //  I made a small change to gulp.src below
   return gulp.src('./app/*.html')
    .pipe(useref())
    .pipe(gulpif('*.js', uglify()))
    .pipe(gulpif('*.css', minifyCss()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

[EDIT : Added your html]

```
<html class="h-100">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Login</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/vendors/clarity-ui/css/clarity-ui.min.css">

  <!-- build:css dist/css/main.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/scss/main.css">
  <!-- endbuild -->

  <!-- build:js ../dist/js/myJS.js -->
  <script src="../src/js/myJS.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild -->

 </head>
```

I assume you do not want to change the already minified vendor css.  So there is no need to put a directive around it.

And useref will not concatenate the vendor css because it will not grab that asset since their is no build directive around it.

You can do something similar for your js files.

[EDIT : added **folder** structure.]

```
-[your working directory]
---[app]
-----test.html
---[src]
------[scss]
--------main.css
------[js]
--------myJS.js
-gulpfile.js
```

So the gulpfile.js is in your base working directory above the app and src folders.

Running gulp html from your working directory will create a 'dist' folder with your minified css and uglified js in it and your modified main.html.

I have run this on a test system with this folder structure and it works perfectly.  Let me know if you still have problems.

Comment: Thanks @Mark but I don't want to concatenate all js or css files. useref use for concatenate asset files. Do you have any idea?

Comment: That is just their example code.  It will NOT concatenate your css, for example, if you put a build directive around each one SEPARATELY .  Have you tried it after putting in the directives into your html file?  The directives say which css or js assets to get and what to rename them to.  Put a directive around each individual css.